# Expand a DraggableScrollableSheet with a button

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to make my `DraggableScrollableSheet` expand when I tap the text "Expand"

I've tried to use `controller.jumpTo()`, but isn't working.
This is my code:

```
void thingTapped(BuildContext context) {
    double a = 0;
    showModalBottomSheet(
      isScrollControlled: true,
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      isDismissible: true,
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return NotificationListener<DraggableScrollableNotification>(
          onNotification: (DraggableScrollableNotification dsNotification) {
            a = dsNotification.extent;
            print("Notification: $a");
            return true;
          },
          child: DraggableScrollableSheet(
            maxChildSize: 0.9,
            minChildSize: 0.15,
            initialChildSize: 0.2,
            snap: true,
            shouldCloseOnMinExtent: true,
            snapSizes: const <double>[0.2, 0.9],
            builder: (context, scrollController) => Card(
              color: Colors.white,
              child: ListView(
                controller: scrollController,
                children: [
                  const Text(
                    "This gonna be a cool title",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                  const Text(
                    "And this gonna be a cooler sub-title :)",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                  ),
                  InkWell(
                    onTap: () => scrollController.animateTo(
                      0.9,
                      curve: Curves.easeIn,
                      duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
                    ),
                    child: const Text(
                      "Expand",
                      style:
                          TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 18),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - Create a draggableScrollableController

2 - Connect draggableScrollableController to `DraggableScrollableSheet`

3 - Then use `draggableScrollableController.animateTo()`

```
 void thingTapped(BuildContext context) {
    final DraggableScrollableController draggableScrollableController = DraggableScrollableController();
    double a = 0;
    showModalBottomSheet(
      isScrollControlled: true,
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      isDismissible: true,
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return NotificationListener<DraggableScrollableNotification>(
          onNotification: (DraggableScrollableNotification dsNotification) {
            a = dsNotification.extent;
            print("Notification: $a");
            return true;
          },
          child: DraggableScrollableSheet(
            controller: draggableScrollableController,
            maxChildSize: 0.9,
            minChildSize: 0.15,
            initialChildSize: 0.2,
            snap: true,
            shouldCloseOnMinExtent: true,
            snapSizes: const <double>[0.2, 0.9],
            builder: (context, scrollController) => Card(
              color: Colors.white,
              child: ListView(
                controller: scrollController,
                children: [
                  const Text(
                    "This gonna be a cool title",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                  const Text(
                    "And this gonna be a cooler sub-title :)",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                  ),
                  InkWell(
                    onTap: () => draggableScrollableController.animateTo(
                      0.9,
                      curve: Curves.easeIn,
                      duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
                    ),
                    child: const Text(
                      "Expand",
                      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 18),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```